# Extract ip address and port from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

In my client side code, the user enter an address like:

```
http://192.168.1.52:8080/home/client.html
```

I would like to extract the **ip address** 192.168.1.52 and **the port number** 8080 separately.

Here is what I did to extract the ip, but failed!

```
var url = window.location.href;
ValidIpAddressRegex = new RegExp("^(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[0-1]?\\d?\\d)(\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[0-1]?\\d?\\d)){3}$");

var ip= ValidIpAddressRegex.exec(url);
alert(ip);
```

What would be the correct way of extracting IP and port number in javascript.- Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`window.location.hostname` and `window.location.port`

Read more about `window.location` at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location

Comment: Yes, this is it.  I didn't realize he was actually getting the value from the window.location :-)

Answer (score 6):

The easiest would be to just use a fake anchor :

```
var str = 'http://192.168.1.52:8080/home/client.html'

var a = document.createElement('a')
a.href = str;
var host = a.hostname;
var post = a.port;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ve5FQ/)

If it's coming from the adressbar, this is already built in to `document.location`

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple method to parse the information from a given URL-string (not necessarily from the actual document.location)

```
<script>
var url = 'http://192.168.1.52:8080/home/client.html';
var ip = url.split('/')[2].split(':')[0];
var port = url.split('/')[2].split(':')[1];
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

if the string is a valid URL you can use this

```
const url = new URL('http://192.168.1.52:8080/home/client.html');
console.log(url.hostname) // 192.168.1.52
console.log(url.port) // 8080
```

note that it'll throw in case the string is is not a valid URL

For the current page URL, as suggested before, use `window.location` object.